# Как привязать к графику значения Entry в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, matplotlib

Есть задание, в котором от значения scrollbox должно появиться некоторое количество entry для ввода данных. Эти данные мне нужно вытащить и привязать их к графику, но есть одна проблема -  название у таких entry одно, и не понятно что будет использовано:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

import random
import time
import sys
from itertools import product
from itertools import cycle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 6, 255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
rgb = (0, 25, 204)
green = (0,255,30)
fiol = (172,91,255)

shirina = 5
start_x = 1
start_y = 2


class Job:

    total_time = 0
    total_y = 0

    def __init__(self, q, time, color):
        self.q = q
        self.time = time
        self.color = color

    def plot(self):
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((Job.total_time,Job.total_y),self.time,1,facecolor = self.color ,edgecolor = 'red',fill=True))
        Job.total_time +=self.time
        Job.total_y -=1





first_group = [ Job(0.4, 50, 'blue'),Job(0.3, 15, 'blue'),Job(0.2, 12, 'blue'),Job(0.1, 20, 'blue') ]
second_group = [ Job(3, 15, 'red'),Job(15, 20, 'red'),Job(2, 16, 'red'),Job(7, 20, 'red'),Job(45, 30, 'red'),Job(1,23, 'red') ]

first_group = sorted(first_group, key=lambda i: i.q)
second_group = sorted(second_group, key=lambda i: i.q)

for i in first_group:
    i.plot()

for i in second_group:
    i.plot()


def click():
    first_group = 
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    ax.plot()
    plt.show()


def update_entries():
    name_to = int(spinbox.get())
    tvip = int(spinbox.get())
    qotk = int(spinbox.get())
    number_group = int(spinbox.get())

    for entry in entries:
        entry.destroy()


    for i in range(name_to):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=0, padx = (0,50))
        entries.append(entry)

    for i in range(tvip):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=1)
        entries.append(entry)

    for i in range(qotk):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=2)
        entries.append(entry)

    for i in range(number_group):
        entry = tk.Entry(root)
        entry.grid(row=8*(i+1), column=3)
        entries.append(entry)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("МТК")
root.geometry("900x600")

label_num = ttk.Label(root, text = "№ маршрута")
label_num.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
spinbox_num = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=20)
spinbox_num.grid(column =1, row = 0)

label_amount = ttk.Label(root, text = "Количество ТО")
label_amount.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=20, command=update_entries)
spinbox.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

label_executor = ttk.Label(root, text = "Исполнитель")
label_executor.grid(column = 3, row= 0 )
entry_executor = ttk.Entry(root)
entry_executor.grid(column = 3, row = 1)
label_insert = ttk.Label(root, text = "Введите данные для построения МТК")
label_insert.grid(column = 2, row = 5, pady = (0,20))

label_name = ttk.Label(root, text = "Наименование")
label_name.grid(column = 0, row = 7, sticky=W)
label_time = ttk.Label(root, text = "tвып")
label_time.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
label_q = ttk.Label(root, text = "q")
label_q.grid(column = 2, row = 7)
label_group = ttk.Label(root, text = "группа")
label_group.grid(column = 3, row = 7)



entries = []

update_entries()

button_run = tk.Button(root, command = click, text = "Построить МТК")
button_run.grid(column = 3, row = 21)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У вас список entries, идете по нему и вытаскиваете значения из этих полей ввода.